# loop query exclude meta_key with meta_value

Tags: loop, meta-query

Hi I use a loop like this:

```
// show all active coupons for this store and setup pagination
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'paged' => $paged
) );
```

Now I have a meta value `meta_key' => 'clpr_excoupon'` it is either 1 or 0.

I would like to exclude all `meta_key' => 'clpr_excoupon'` with `'meta_value'=> 0,` and also 'NOT EXISTS' need help!!

Comment: If *any* of the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Do **NOT** use `query_posts()` - it is **bad**, very bad to be exact.

For more information read:

- [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/22534)
- [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/22534)

Use `WP_Query` instead.

Example with `meta_key`, `meta_value` and `meta_compare` parameters in use:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'clpr_excoupon',
    'meta_value'   => '0',
    'meta_compare' => '!='
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Note: those parameters work for `query_posts` too, but as said, you shouldn't use it.

---

Update:

With `NOT EXISTS` compare.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'clpr_excoupon',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            'value'   => 'prior to WP 3.9 a value was needed due to bug #23268'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'clpr_excoupon',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'value'   => '0'
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer however I cant get it to work, i have other loops on the same page with query_posts(). How do i exchange the query_posts() for WP_Query?

Comment: I really can't account for you making the wrong specification, right? Aside from that the answer is correct. @IngoMeinhard

Comment: somebody is having a bad day, i was not complaining and thank you for pushing me in the right direction .....

Comment: Sorry, if it came across that way, but all is good on my side. Believe me, you don't want to get in my way, if I am really having a bad day. @IngoMeinhard

Answer (score -1):

You should use 2 queries for this:

```
$excluded = query_posts( array(
        'meta_key=> 'clpr_excoupon';
        'meta_value' => '0'
) );

//$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array(
    'post__not_in => $excluded;
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    //'paged' => $paged
) );
```

with this code you will get all the posts that have the clpr_excoupon with value 1 :)

Hope this helps...

Cheers,
Mile

Comment: -1 for using `query_posts`, and you have obvious syntax errors in your code

Comment: -1 because i want to show alle post without pagination

Answer (score -2):

It is working with this, thanks @ialocin for your help :

```
// show all active coupons for this store and setup pagination
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    query_posts( array(
                        'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
                        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'clpr_excoupon',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'

    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'clpr_excoupon',
        'compare' => '!=',
        'value'   => '1'
    ),
),
                        'paged' => $paged
                    ) );
```

Comment: strange i needed 1 to not show it????

Comment: -1 for using `query_posts`

Comment: well its in my theme and i do not want to change the hole theme. Instead of -1 you could explain how to change to WP_Query