# Exclude post on loop by multiple meta key value

Tags: wp-query, loop, meta-query

I need to exclude the loop two post with different values in your meta key (the same). I investigating got this code that works fine if I enter only one value in `value =>`. But if I want to enter two values it gives me error.

```
$args = array(
    'cat'           => 1,
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'  => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'Caja',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'Caja',
            'value'   => array('UNO','DOS'), // Here I return an error php: Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
            'compare' => '!='
        ),
    ),
);
```

I used [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189138/loop-query-exclude-meta-key-with-meta-value) as a reference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your query is inherently expensive, especially the NOT EXISTS parameter, it would be significantly faster to specify what you want rather than what you don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

> **`value`** (string|array) - Custom field value. It can be an array only when compare is 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'.

### SOLUTION

Change `compare' => '!='` to `compare' => 'NOT IN'`