# Conflict array_splice on loop and query in widget

Tags: posts, wp-query

I am using the function array_slice to insert two post within the loop in the index.

```
function insert_post_wpse_96347($posts) {
  global $wp_query;
  $args = array('meta_key' => 'Caja', 'meta_value' => array('UNO','DOS'), 'post__not_in' => get_option("sticky_posts"), 'posts_per_page' => '2','suppress_filters'=>true);

  if (is_main_query() && is_home() &&  0 == get_query_var('paged')) {
    $p2insert = new WP_Query($args);
    $insert_at = 0;
    if (!empty($p2insert->posts)) {
      array_splice($posts,$insert_at,0,$p2insert->posts);
    }
  }
  return $posts;
}
add_filter('posts_results','insert_post_wpse_96347');
```

And I have also created a plugin to show me the most viewed post. This plugin worked before the previous function added.

```
/* set view post */
function observePostViews($postID) {
  $count_key = 'post_views_count';
  $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
  if ($count=='') {
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
  } else {
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
  }
}
```

My plugin is only one copy of the widget [class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/77e365efbf2e499e2ed11d29c101ea466cf1ceed/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php) and I've only changed the `WP_Query` using `'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` that I created as shown above.

In place of the widget, instead of displaying the post with more visits, it shows me the two post with the `'meta_key' => 'box', 'meta_value' => array('ONE','DOS')`

How could resolve this conflict? Array_splice that only applied to the loop and not all query my home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite messy which makes debugging hard, so I cleaned up your code a bit.

The [`posts_results` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_results/) accepts two parameters, one being the posts results array, and the second one is the current `WP_Query` instance. So you can pass the second argument and then test for your conditions.

I haven't tested your code, just cleaned it up and added the second parameter. The following should work: (*REQUIRES PHP 5.4+*)

```
add_filter( 'posts_results', 'insert_post_wpse_96347', 10, 2 );
function insert_post_wpse_96347( $posts, \WP_Query $q ) 
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    if (    $q->is_main_query() 
         && $q->is_home() &&  
         0 == get_query_var( 'paged' ) 
     ) {

        $args = [
            'meta_key'         => 'Caja', 
            'meta_value'       => ['UNO','DOS'], 
            'post__not_in'     => get_option( "sticky_posts" ), 
            'posts_per_page'   => '2',
            'suppress_filters' =>true
        ];

        $p2insert = new WP_Query($args);
        $insert_at = 0;
        if ( !empty( $p2insert->posts ) ) {
            array_splice( $posts, $insert_at, 0, $p2insert->posts );
        }
    }
  return $posts;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked!

Comment: Glad it worked, enjoy ;-)

Comment: However these two post are repeated in the loop, how can I avoid that?

Comment: Do you need to display two different posts on each page or just remove the custom posts as from page 2 onwards?

Comment: The idea is to highlight two news items that appear at the beginning of the loop, therefore should not appear below. I have [asked before](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218584/exclude-post-on-loop-by-multiple-meta-key-value), but with the function described in this question, does not work.

Comment: You should ask a new question. This is out of scope of this question ;-)